# Blender Cycles won't render animations

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, animation

I'm trying to render a 60 frame animation of a crystal hovering in a small dungeon but for some reason it wont render the whole thing, just one frame

This problem has been going on for quite some time, i never really cared but now it's quite annoying.

[image]

Comment: Please don't edit the title to show the question is solved; marking accepted answer is enough.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You had your frame step set to zero. Meaning after it finishes a frame it is done. 
Make sure it is set to 1.

Also make sure your file output actually exist and it is not trying to save to a folder that doesnt exist.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! It works now, also the folder is real, i think you just don't have a folder named the same as mine so you can't find it